# PUBLICATION IN IJBSS IN 2012

Tags: social-science

our publication in IJBSS was printed with all the names of the scholars but in the online version, two names were missing for a year or two, now they have included it in the online version, it this ethically correct

Comment: What dos IJBSS stand for?

Comment: What is wrong with them correcting it?

Comment: As it stands, this question is lacking information: 1) Did the journal know about the mistake? 2) Why didn’t they fix it? 3) Why are you interested in this? Probably everybody agrees that (serious) known mistakes such as these should be fixed as soon as possible, so what are you unsure about? 4) Do you have any reason to believe that this was done intentionally? — Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: How long did you take to spot the omission?

Answer (score 2):

Omitting two authors from the online publication is a rather serious oversight by the journal. It is unprofessional and should have been fixed much earlier than after "a year or two". The issue has nothing to do with "ethics", though.

Comment: Less serious than the authors using the wrong data or references...

Comment: Not "unethical" anyway.

Comment: If there were hundreds of authors (or maybe even tens) then it might just be an oversight. Surprised that none of the authors caught it, of course.